# Supplied key (sun.security.mscapi.CPrivateKey) is not a RSAPrivateKey instance (DIGITAL SIGNATURE)

Tags: java, rsa, digital-signature, bouncycastle, electronic-signature

So i'm reading the certificate, privatekey..etc from a usb dongle and i try to sign a pdf, but it gives me the following exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.InvalidKeyException: Supplied key (sun.security.mscapi.CPrivateKey) is not a RSAPrivateKey instance
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.DigestSignatureSpi.engineInitSign(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.Signature$Delegate.engineInitSign(Signature.java:1370)
    at java.base/java.security.Signature.initSign(Signature.java:635)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PrivateKeySignature.sign(PrivateKeySignature.java:114)
```

Here i'm using the com.itextpdf.text library (MakeSignature, ExternalSignature and some other classes) and this is what my -main- code looks like :

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY");
        keyStore.load(null, password.toCharArray());
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(keyStore.aliases().nextElement().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        keyStore.load(in, password.toCharArray());

        String alias = keyStore.aliases().nextElement();
        PrivateKey pk = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey(alias, password.toCharArray());
        java.security.cert.Certificate[] chain =  keyStore.getCertificateChain(alias);
        BouncyCastleProvider provider = new BouncyCastleProvider();
        Security.addProvider(provider);
        ExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();

        ExternalSignature signature = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, DigestAlgorithms.SHA1, provider.getName());
        System.out.println(signature.getEncryptionAlgorithm());
        System.out.println(signature.getHashAlgorithm());
        MakeSignature.signDetached(appearance, digest, signature, chain, null, null, null,
                0, MakeSignature.CryptoStandard.CADES);
        pdf.close();
        reader.close();
        os.close();
```

**what i want to know is where does the incompatibility lay ??**
is it between the pk algorithm and the provider ?
or is it between the signing class and the pk ? cuz afterall i get the privatekey from the dongle and i cannot change it! Which would mean i need to change something else in my program.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: The incompatibility is between the provider you specified (BouncyCastle aka BC) and the key which is accessed _in_ the dongle (not read from it) using the _SunMSCAPI_ provider. **Specify SunMSCAPI instead.**

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 that was indeed the problem, i got it working after specifying SunMSCAPI whith bouncycastle constructor.. thank you

Comment: @ImraneAkkouh If you have a working solution feel free to post it as answer, so other developer running into the same problem can understand how to solve this problem.